# Npm package @paypal/react-paypal-js gives cors error

Tags: reactjs, paypal, paypal-sandbox

I am following this blog:
[react and paypal integration](https://www.unimedia.tech/2021/10/09/paypal-checkout-integration-with-react/)

When I run this code:

```
actions.order
            .create({
                purchase_units: [
                    {
                        description: "Sunflower",
                        amount: {
                            currency_code: "USD",
                            value: 20,
                        },
                    },
                ],
                // not needed if a shipping address is actually needed
                application_context: {
                    shipping_preference: "NO_SHIPPING",
                },
            })
            .then((orderID) => {
                setOrderID(orderID);
                return orderID;
            });
```

Pop up shows and when I try to login
I get the following error:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://c.paypal.com/v1/r/d/b/pa' from origin 'https://c.sandbox.paypal.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status.
```

I am trying to log in from the same account that API is created from

Comment: That's not an issue, ignore it. Are you having any other actual problem?

Comment: @PrestonPHX yes, can't log in, even though credentials are valid